# Combine a List of dataframe records into a single dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a for loop that fetches forex data from alphavantage for each currency code in a seperate dataframe and ultimately generates multiple dataframes with the forex information. This function looks like this:

```py
frames = []

for i, j in countrydf.iterrows():
    if j['base_currency'] != j['currency_cde']:
        CSV = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=FX_MONTHLY'\
        '&from_symbol={0}'\
        '&to_symbol={1}'\
        '&outputsize=full'\
        '&datatype=csv'\
        '&apikey={apikey_goes_here}'.format(j['base_currency'], j['currency_cde'])
        try:
            forex_ = pd.read_csv(CSV, usecols=[0, 4], parse_dates=['timestamp'])
            forex.rename(columns={'timestamp': 'date', 'close': 'rate'}, inplace=True)
            forex.sort_values(by='date', inplace=True)
            forex = forex[(forex['date'] > j['start']) & (forex['date'] < j['end'])]
            forex['ctry_cde'] = j['ctry_cde']
            frames.append(forex)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Forex figures for {0} are not present'.format(j['ctry_desc']))
    else:
        continue
    print()
```

These dataframes are iteratively appended to a list which gives me a list that looks like this

[image]

How do I convert this list of dataframes into one big dataframe? I need something that works like `bind_rows()` in `R`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
pd.concat(your_list)
```

Comment: Oh I thought this only works for cases where you have a list of dataframe names, not actual records. I feel like an idiot right now

Comment: No need to, the library is complex and if you come from a different language there is always a learning curve ;)