# Python while loop that does 5 iterations every 60 seconds

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I have a python function which requests forex data from [alphavantage.co](https://www.alphavantage.co/). However the problem I'm having is that I need the requests to "pause" after every 5 iterations for 60 seconds as the alphavantage documentation stipulates that I can only make 5 requests per minute.

I've attempted to build a simple while loop as I thought this would be the best approach, but I'm not winning. The while loop I've built does exactly 6 iterations of the first element, sleeps for 5 seconds and exits the loop. This is what it looks like

```py
import time
items = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
n = 0
for i in items:
    while n < 6:
        print(i)
        n = n + 1
    else:
        time.sleep(5) # Delay for 5 seconds (5 seconds).
```

output:

```py
A
A
A
A
A
A
```

This is what I expect:

```py
A
B
C
D
E
# delay for 5 seconds
F
G
H
I
# exit loop
```

My knowledge on while loops is evidently limited. I'd appreciate some help on this. Even if it's a completely different approach, as long as I can pause a loop for a certain amount of time after a certain number of iterations. If you'd like to see the actual function I have it on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68641636/combine-a-list-of-dataframe-records-into-a-single-dataframe-in-python)

Comment: Could pausing for 12 seconds after every iteration be a plausible answer?

Comment: Please confirm: you want to loop over the items, and after every 5th one, want to pause for 30 seconds?

Comment: Use `if` instead of `while`.

Comment: If you need 5 request / minute, why don't you sleep 12s after each run? Is it mandatory to sleep after 5 continous iterations?

Comment: you never change ``i`` in your while loop hence it always remains ``"A"``

Comment: @Jerrybibo, perhaps. I'm not sure if that will do the trick. If I can't pause after every 5 iterations I'd rather just pause for a minute for each iteration to avoid possible complications. `Scott Hunter`, Yes, but I'd like to pause for 60 seconds, not 30. `nagyl` as I said to jerrybibo I'm not sure if that solution would help but if I have to take that route I'd rather pause for 1 minute for each iteration

Comment: I don't think I should explain basic math. You have 5 requests in 60 seconds, you can schedule them the way you want. If it isn't mandatory to wait 60s after 5 continous run, I'm sure sleeping 12s 5 times would do the job.

Comment: @nagyl, no I get the math behind it. What I'm thinking is that I have a 1 minute window for 5 total requests and another 1 minute window as a "cooling off" period. So requesting every 12 seconds might cause an issue because in the 1 minute of requesting I'd have used up all my 5 requests and then the 6th request will fail because I basically would have waited 12 seconds as opposed to 1 minute.

Comment: What you *really* want is to issue 5 requests, and then wait *just* long enough to close the 1 minute window.

Comment: @ScottHunter, yes sir. Hence I don't think the 12s method will work well.

Comment: I don't see how the 12s method gets you in trouble (if every item takes NO time at all, it still takes 1 full minute to go through 5 of 'em), it just may take longer than necessary (but no longer that waiting a full minute every 5 items).

Comment: @ScottHunter So every 12s a request is sent to the API. After 5 iterations the 1 minute window for requests closes, right? Now iteration number 6 is sent to the API after 12s again, but we're still in the 1 minute cooling off period. That 6th iteration will fail because it was sent after 12s and not after the 1 minute cooling off period. Also let me clarify that I can't do more than 5 requests within the 1 minute window for requests. So even if there's a 2 second waiting period between my requests I can only make up to 5 requests at 1 minute intervals

Comment: Where did you read about this "cooling off period"?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

While you are in the `while` loop,  `i` never changed. If you want the result to be like you expected you can do it like this:

```
import time
items = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
n = 0
for i in items:
    print(i)
    n = n + 1
    if n % 5 == 0 and n != 1:
        time.sleep(5) # Delay for 5 seconds (5 seconds).
```

without even using a while loop.

and of course, if you want to pause for 60 seconds, just change it in the `time.sleep()` function.

Comment: This will not work as desired for long enough lists..

Comment: @ScottHunter why? I can't see the problem here

Comment: Did you *try* it with a list long enough to need 2 or 3 pauses?

Comment: @Elad, thank you for this. I'm choosing your answer as it integrates better with what I already have. I won't have to change too many things in my actual function

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you describe:

```
for n,i in enumerate(items):
    print(i)
    if n%5 == 4:
        time.sleep(5) # Your text said 60 seconds, but your code said 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `while` loop doesn't make any sense. You need to check your iteration and if it is divisible by 5 sleep. To obtain the index of the iteration you can use `enumerate` function:

```
import time
items = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']

for i, item in enumerate(items):
    print(item)
    if i % 5 == 4: # each fifth iteration
        time.sleep(60)
```

another approach is to sleep 12 seconds each iteration:

```
import time
items = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']

for item in items:
    print(item)
    time.sleep(12)
```

Comment: thanks for this. I've chosen `Elads` answer as it seamlessly integrates with what I already have in my actual function. Yours also works of course